# Using dp makes my app's screen responsive?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to know if using dp in my layouts makes my app responsive for all the screens ?
If no, what makes my app responsive ?

For making my app responsive i have been using constraint layout but it is a little bit hard for me.

Comment: You can create dimen.xml file for different screen sizes. Alternatively, you can use a third-party library like sdp. The recommended way is to use constraint layout.

Comment: *dp* measurements just allow you to define real-world sizes for things - 160dp is about an inch *on every screen*, so you can get consistent sizes without worrying about high-res screens having more pixels etc. But different screens *are different sizes*, with *different amounts of space* - a watch is smaller than a compact phone, which is smaller than a big phone, which is smaller than a tablet. So your design can't rely on having *X dp* of width available, and has to adapt to different amounts of available space. `ConstraintLayout` helps with that, but it takes work, yeah

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes  gives you some info about things you have to consider